# Vocês conhecem algum recurso exclusivo do PostgreSQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Queria saber se existe alguma função ou recurso exclusivo do PostgreSQL, algo que não tenha nos outros SGBD's.

Answer (score 1):

Difícil dizer que um recurso é exclusivo do PostgreSQL pois isto implicaria em conhecer a fundo todos os SGBD existentes (e que são muitos) em sua diversas versões.

Creio que além do usuário poder escrever funções em C e SQL poder implementar funções em diversas linguagens de paradigma procedimental (PL/pgSQL, PL/Tcl, PL/Perl, PL/Python, PL/Java, PL/Lua, dentre outras) é uma característica não encontrada na maioria dos SGBD.